# Problems with shifting a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shift

this is my code and I have a few problems:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import shift

index_default = np.array([2, 4])
b = np.zeros((5, 5), dtype=float)
f = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
 m = np.array([[1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
              [1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
              [1, 2, 1, 2, 0],
              [1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
              [1, 2, 1, 2, 1]])

for index, x in np.ndenumerate(f):
 if x == 1:
    a = np.asarray(index)
    y = np.subtract(a, index_default)
    m_shift = shift(m, (y[0], y[1]), cval=0)
    b += np.add(m_shift, b)
    print(m_shift)
    print(b)
```

SO, when i just want to print m_shift, the code will show me only two m_shift arrays. If i run this code as depicted with print(b) it will show me THREE m_shift arrays. Furthermore it calculate not intuitively. For me output should be:

```
f = np.array([[2, 4, 2, 4, 1],
              [2, 4, 2, 4, 2],
              [2, 4, 2, 4, 1],
              [1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
              [1, 2, 1 ,2, 1]])
```

I think the += operator creates the problems. But i think i have to use it because i want to keep the result from the loop and to not overwrite it

Answer (score 0):

Change the b+= to b=.

```
b+= ... # corresponds to  b = b + add(m_shift,b)
        # net effect is that b = b + m_shift + b I think you intend b=b+m_shift   

b+=m_shift # probably works too.
```